# How do I find out all supported interfaces of a type in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When using **3rd party dlls**, sometimes it can be handy if I can know what interfaces a type implemented. E.g., for a class XYZ, I'd like to know whether it implements ISerializable, IDisposable, ISupportInitialize, etc.

---

I don't think going to definition solves the problems. Say if X inherits Y which inherits Z, Y implements IY and Z implements IZ, then I can't tell wheter X implements IZ.

---

I'm using Visual Studio 2010/2012/2013 (I'm a junior developer and I actually don't know what other IDE I can use to program C#). @Michael Gray: I can only go 1 level when I check definition of a type in a 3rd party dll, I can't go any further to see what type that type inherits. I raised this question because I am having this problem with a devexpress type, and I have tried this approach and also checked their online documentation which doesn't help.

Comment: F12 - go to type definition. Also reading documentation might be helpful

Comment: apart from looking at the code or using `is` to check if `XYZ` is an `ISerializable` etc?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Not sure why this question got so many downvotes, it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: In response to your edit, you can keep going through the chains and find out eventually where things are. It's a little more challenging and time consuming. You could refine your question to specify a programmatic approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Progrmming time:

Visual Studio: Open Object Browser on DLL, find type, read.

Runtime:

GetType on an instance gives you a type object. It has methods you can call.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.type

FindInterfaces is a nice method on it.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.type.findinterfaces(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.type.findinterfaces%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Learning time:

Read the documentation.

Comment: Thank you @TomTom. You can edit your answer to keep only the Runtime part as the other 2 approaches are not effective. I'll mark your answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can place your cursor over the type name and press F12. This will bring you to the definition of the type. From there, you can see what interfaces it implements.

If you do not use Visual Studio or any other IDE, you can find the documentation on MSDN and determine what interfaces it implements, assuming it is part of .NET or any other Microsoft framework.

If it's not a Microsoft created type or the documentation is unavailable on MSDN, you can use the ILDASM tool included in .NET to disassemble the assembly and locate the type in question and view the inherited types or interfaces.